# What's the meaning of Philanthropy's biggest contributor?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-series, metal-gear-solid-2-sons-of-liberty

In the epilogue, it's revealed that

> the biggest Philanthropy's contributor is a member of Wisemen's Committee and that he and the other Wisemen are dead for about hundred years.

How this relates to the overall story of Metal Gear series? Why would them fund Philanthropy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIRC the Wiseman's Committee itself is a fake front for their successors, the Patriots. By the time of Solid Snake, the Patriots have so many gambits running in parallel that one is that they can use Philanthropy as a way to get Snake do things they want. Need a scapegoat? Leak a new Metal Gear for Snake to show up and take the blame. Need to control Ocelot's plots? Send in Snake to take him out.